# Multiway frequency Table in R

Tags: r

I have data.frame that has the following fields:

```
State    County    Race
FL       Broward   Black
FL       Broward   White
GA       DeKalb    White
GA       Fulton    Hispanic
```

And so on. What I need is a count for each `race` (as it's own variable) within a unique `State - County` combination, and I want to keep 0s and also get a total. So for the above example, I want to get:

```
State    County   White    Black    Hispanic    Total
FL       Broward    1        1        0           2
GA       DeKalb     1        0        0           1
GA       Fulton     0        0        1           1
```

I can get the totals by `state-county` using the `{plyr}` package :

```
count(deaths,c("State","County"))
```

But when I add in the additional race layer I get each race on its own row, rather than a column. The output looks like this:

```
State     County      Race      Freq
TX         Bee       Unknown     1
TX         Bee       White       1
TX         Bell      Black       1
TX         Bell      Unknown     3
TX         Bell      White       3
```

How can I get this in the format I need?

Comment: I don't know where you found this `count` function, but `table` is probably what you want. Oh, now I see your mention of plyr. Common practice here to include `library(plyr)` somewhere in the body of the code, fyi.

Comment: When I tried table(deaths$State,deaths$County,deaths$Race), it used state as the row, then county as a column. These both need to be a row, and only race counted and added across as columns.

Comment: Ah ok, that's more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "data.table" you can try:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(as.data.table(mydf)[, count := .N, by = names(mydf)], 
      State + County ~ Race, fun = c, value.var = "count", fill = 0)[
        , Total := rowSums(.SD), by = .(State, County)][]
#    State  County Black Hispanic White Total
# 1:    FL Broward     1        0     1     2
# 2:    GA  DeKalb     0        0     1     1
# 3:    GA  Fulton     0        1     0     1
```

---

I can't seem to save any verbosity by not first creating the "count" column. Here's what I came up with trying to handle it directly in `dcast`:

```
dcast(as.data.table(mydf), State + County ~ Race, 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) as.numeric(!is.na(x)), fill = 0)[
        , Total := rowSums(.SD), by = .(State, County)][]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `count` from dplyr and then `spread` the data to make it wide:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% count(State, County, Race) %>%
        spread(Race, n, fill = 0) %>%
        mutate(total = rowSums(.[sapply(., is.numeric)]))

Source: local data frame [3 x 6]

   State  County Black Hispanic White total
  (fctr)  (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     FL Broward     1        0     1     2
2     GA  DeKalb     0        0     1     1
3     GA  Fulton     0        1     0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt = read.table(text="State    County    Race
                FL       Broward   Black
                FL       Broward   White
                GA       DeKalb    White
                GA       Fulton    Hispanic", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(State,County) %>%
  mutate(Total = n()) %>%
  count(State,County,Race,Total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(Race,n, fill=0) %>%
  select(-matches("Total"), Total)

#     State  County Black Hispanic White Total
#    (fctr)  (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl) (int)
# 1     FL Broward     1        0     1     2
# 2     GA  DeKalb     0        0     1     1
# 3     GA  Fulton     0        1     0     1
```

Comment: Just noticed it's very similar to @jeremycg 's answer. I'm happy to remove the answer if he adds the `Total` calculation. :-)

Comment: I kept getting the following error: "Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "group_by"" for some reason. Obviously the function works, and I even manually updated the package. Weird.

Comment: No idea why is that. Maybe your R version? Have you used `dplyr` before? Can you open a new R session in a clear working space and run this small example?